# Large assets in play framework 2.1

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0, assets

I have a huge directory of data (~30GB) which contains files i'd like to serve in my Play application. When I place the directory in the public folder, the application wont finish compiling and will just hang on compilation

I've already tried something like:

```
GET  /liabilities/*file          controllers.Assets.at("/foo", file)
```

and in the Build.scala file

```
// Add your own project settings here
playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "foo"
```

However, I get the same issue as above.

I've also tried `ExternalAssets`

Some of the files being served are used in javascript so I cannot have them on a separate local ftp server or javascript will complain.

Ideas?

Comment: Where are you gonna to publish it ? some cloud, custom VPS, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a quick and dirty solution. When setting up a simple http webserver (e.g [python simple webserver](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python)), you need to enable [cross origin resource sharing](http://enable-cors.org/) which will allow javascript to access files from different domains.

CORS is built into in several webservers, but not pythons. I found a script that that will do this for python. [See here](https://gist.github.com/enjalot/2904124/download)

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't need (and as you can see in your case) you don't even should place assets in apps directory, instead consider two possibilities:

1. [Frontend HTTP server](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/HTTPServer), for an example [nginx](http://nginx.org/), light and fast will allow you to create a reverse proxy and/or [aliases](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), so you can just serve files directly from disk within address `http://domain.tld/public` - in such case you need to write paths manually instead of using `Assets.at(...)`. Actually using this approach you can also serve common assets, such as layout's CSS'es, images etc.
2. Use some professional CDN or cloud storage, anyway in this case you will need to rebuild your scripts a little.